# Any bug tracking addin for Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, bug-tracking

I don't want a fancy bug tracking suite. Sometimes I am working on projects/tools for myself, and I just want to keep track of any bugs, features, etc.. as I go along. I keep these in TODO and a bugs.txt for now, but it would be nice if there was a typical bug tracking system that would be stored with the project or solution file itself.

EDIT: To clarify, if I have to run any server portion to access it (website, database, etc..) then it becomes sort of useless to me. I want it stored with the project itself so that I can open it up on multiple computers.

Comment: Do you use source control? If so, what kind?

Comment: I do not use source control per se for my personal projects such as this. I keep my dev folder on Dropbox which gets file revisions, just not 'named' revisions like I would like.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another free for single user product is Axosoft's OnTime.  It has a Windows client, as well as integrating with Visual Studio.  Uses MS SQL Server as store, and supports SQL EXpress, so it's still free.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is closest to what I want, if it supported SQL compact framework files so that the database is portable it would be near perfect.

Comment: their web site is a major turn-off

Answer (score 12):

[Fogbugz](http://www.fogbugz.com) is a great solution.
However, I'm not sure this classes as a suite or not. It maybe does.
It has some useful features which include (in addition to the website), [Visual Studio integration](http://our.fogbugz.com/default.asp?W984) and [Source Control intergration](http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBugz/docs/70/topics/advanced/SourceControlIntegration.html). You can even add comments in your code to tie your fixes, bugs and code together.

Comment: Where are the VS integration plugins? I looked around the plugins section of the site and couldn't find one.

Comment: It's not in the plug-ins section. The Visual studio integration is a separate download (http://our.fogbugz.com/default.asp?W984). It isn't bad.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that if this is just for yourself, FogBugz has a "Student & Startup Edition" that you could use free of charge.

This won't be included with with your project file naively, but web-based with the VS plugin is probably second best.

Comment: I'm using the student and startup edition (well, until I hire my next developer - yay for making money) and I had no idea that there was a vs plugin. +1 johnfx and amadiere

Comment: I didn't even realise there was a student and start-up edition, I have just switched to that until I hire more people. +1 from me

Answer (score 6):

[OnTime](http://www.axosoft.com/ontime/try_ontime_free/download) by Axosoft has a VS.Net add-in, and it's free for a single user.

Comment: their web site is a major turn-off

Answer (score 2):

Since it appears that Visual Studio integration is important to you, I would recommend [Visual Studio Team System](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/teamsystem/default.aspx).

If IDE integration wasn't so important to you, I would recommend [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/).

Comment: Odd, I have Team System, and I do not see any bug tracking pieces in it. If it requires TFS, then that's sort of what I mean by 'suite', I don't want to have to run a server somewhere.

Comment: VSTS is pretty much the definition of a "Fancy bug tracking suite"

Comment: A consultant I know rants and raves about VSTS integrated bug tracking. We use Redmine in my department and I love it... Very versatile/configurable.

Comment: If you haven't heard of Redmine before, you should know it's web-based. Their site is actually an instance of itself so you become familiar with the product as you browse their site. Best of all, it's open source. Check it out!

Comment: I think this requires Tools->Connect to Server, and it is this 'server' portion that I don't have.

Answer (score 1):

I use SourceGear Fortress  which provides a very nice cost effective ALM suite which integrates quite well into Visual Studio and a single user license is free

Answer (score -1):

Jira also has a free [visual studio connector](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/PLVS) and is free for non commercial projects.

Answer (score -1):

You might like this project: https://github.com/kig/gitbug

It stores the bugs in the repo using a git extension. No VS integration though...

Another one: http://www.eqqon.com/index.php/TicGit.net

Comment: Please don't post answers on obviously off-topic questions! [See: **Should one advise on off topic questions?**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276572/1768232) Off-topic questions can be closed and deleted, which could nullify your contribution. This question is off-topic for being an off-site resource request as per the [help/on-topic].